# OpenFileDialog - png files not shows in dialog

Tags: vb.net, openfiledialog

I set the `OpenFileDialog` with a filter:

```
"Image files (*.png) | *.png"
```

but `png` files are not shown.

I have also tried this filer, it works but just with `jpg` files. `PNGs` are not shown:

```
"Image files (*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.png) | *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.png"
```

Code to open:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        Try
            Dim filePath = OpenFileDialog1.FileName

            For Each files In OpenFileDialog1.FileNames
                DataGrid_List.Rows.Add(files, "")
            Next
        Catch
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

[image: Filter]

Comment: please ask your questions in english. thanks

Comment: Sorry, it is my first question. I translated it in english

Comment: can't reproduce. can you show the code you used?

Comment: are you sure that you are in the correct folder? Have you set the initial directory? In any case you can procede by steps :  for first be sure that all files filter are recognized, after that try an image filter like "Image files (*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.jpe, *.jfif, *.png) | *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.jpe; *.jfif; *.png".

Comment: thank you for your comment, i have my question expanded

Comment: `OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Image files (*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.png)|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png"`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
ofd.Filter = "Image files (*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.png) |*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.png"
```

If this doesn't work I think your picture isn't png.

Comment: Thanks, it works! I have just tested, it works as a Code, but still not working in Properties->Filter. Interesting..

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try this:

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click 
     OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Image files (*.jpg, *.jpeg, .png) |.jpg; *.jpeg; *.png" ' before you can try all files to be sure to have some files.
     OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:\" ' put here that right path
     Dim result As DialogResult = OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog
     If result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

       'your logic code

     End if
  End Sub
```

before to set the filter property try with "All files (*.*)|*.*" just to be sure that you can recognize png files